# value of $a$ for which $25^x+(a+2)5^x-(a+3)<0$for at least one real $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the values of $a$ for which the inequality is satisfied for $25^x+(a+2)5^x-(a+3)<0$
>
> for at least one real value of $x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $a(5^x-1)<-\left[25^x+2\cdot 5^x-3\right]$

So $$a < -\left(\frac{25^x-5^x+3\cdot 5^x-3}{5^x-1}\right) = -\frac{(5^x+3)(5^x-1)}{5^x-1} = -(5^x+3)$$

Now how can i solve after that help required, Thanks

Comment: Hint: let $y=5^x$, look at $y^2+(a+2)y-(a+3) \lt 0$.

Comment: hint: turn it to quadratic equation by :$5^x=z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(5^x)^2+(a+2)5^x-(a+3)=(5^x+a+3)(5^x-1)<0$$

If $5^x-1>0,1<5^x<-(a+3)$ which is possible if $1<-(a+3)\iff a<-4$

If $5^x-1<0,-(a+3)<5^x<1$ which is possible if $1>-(a+3)\iff a>-4$

So, we need $a\ne4$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$(5^x)^2+(a+2)5^x-(a+3)=-y$$

As $5^x$ is real, we need the discriminant  $$(a+2)^2-4(y-a-3)\ge0$$

$$4y\le a^2+8a+16=(a+4)^2$$

Now we need $y>0$ which will be true if $(a+4)^2>0$ which is true for $a+4\ne0\iff a\ne-4$

Answer (score 1):

$z=5^x \to $ $z^2+(a+2)z-(a+3) \lt 0$

now $ \\ \Delta = \to (a+2)^2-4(1)(-(a+3)) = \\a^2+4+4a+4a+12=a^2+8a+16=(a+4)^2 \geq0 \\$

now $$z=\frac{-(a+2)\pm \sqrt{(a+4)^2}}{2}=\\z=1 ,z=-(a+3)\\z=1 \to 5^x=1 \to x=0\\ (5^x-1)(5^x+a+3)<0$$