# values of $k$ for which $\displaystyle 4^t-(k-4)2^t+\frac{9}{4}<0\forall t \in (1,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all values of $k$ for which $\displaystyle 4^t-(k-4)2^t+\frac{9}{4}k<0\forall t \in (1,2)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $2^t = y\;,$ The inequality convert into $\displaystyle y^2-(k-4)y+\frac{9}{4}<0$ and $2<y<4$

*Using Jack D'Aurizio's hint*

Let $\displaystyle f(y) = y^2-(k-4)y+\frac{9}{4}$ is an upward parabola and $f(y)<0$ for $y\in (2,4)$

So $f(2)<0$ and $f(4)<0$

So $\displaystyle 4-(k-4)2+\frac{9}{4}<0$ and $\displaystyle 16-(k-4)4+\frac{9}{4}<0$

Now how can I solve it? Help required. Thanks.

Comment: Really? At $\approx 30k$ you are not able to find which slopes ensure that a line lies above a parabola, on a given interval?

Comment: How is this essentially different from your previous (asked, and answered, and accepted) [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983956/value-of-a-for-which-25xa25x-a30for-at-least-one-real-x)?

Comment: Hint: $y^2+4y+9/4$ is a convex function on $(2,4)$. A line through the origin has to lie above such graph. Is it enough to check that $\geq $ holds at $y=2$ and $y=4$?

Comment: If you are really desperate, you may just sketch a graph and start believing that the inequality is fulfilled for every $k\geq 8+\frac{9}{16}$.

Comment: Thanks  Jack D'Aurizio Got it.

Comment: Is it $4^t-(k-4)2^t+\frac{9}{4}k<0$ as in the title or $4^t-(k-4)2^t+\frac{9}{4}<0$ as in the body ?